# Splitting string into one with numerical data and other with non numerical data

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am reading account details(account name and account balance) to a string array. The typical values would be like `{"Cash on hand -4871266","SB Account 976369","Current Account 980980"}`. I want to split the string array into two - the first array should contain account name and the second array should contain account balance. I can not split the array based on whitespace since the account name may contain space. How can I achieve this in Java

Comment: split accepts regex, so you can split on the last whitespace

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions (java.util.regex.Pattern). You can then split like "group of characters" whitespace "number"

Comment: Look for the rightmost space :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring()` to split, and `lastIndexOf()` to get the last index of space.

```
String x[] = {"Cash on hand -4871266","SB Account 976369","Current Account 980980"};
String arr1[] = new String[x.length], arr2[] = new String[x.length];

for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{
    arr1[i] = x[i].substring(0,x[i].lastIndexOf(" ")); //account name
    arr2[i] = x[i].substring(x[i].lastIndexOf(" ")+1); //value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If account name doesnt include numbers then you could use the patter `-?\\d+` to strip out amount

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
String[] accounts = {"Cash on hand -4871266","SB Account 976369","Current Account 980980"};
for(String account :  accounts){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(account);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

        stringList.add("Cash on hand -4871266");
        stringList.add("SB Account 976369");
        stringList.add("Current Account 980980");

        for (String str : stringList) {
            // Extracts the left hand-side of your string
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[\\s-+][0-9]+", ""));
            // Extracts the right hand-side of your string
            Pattern testPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s-+][0-9]+");
            Matcher matcher = testPattern.matcher(str);
            matcher.find();
            System.out.println(matcher.group().trim());
        }
    }

}
```